# WHMCS admin/configregistrars.php Header doesn't seem

Tags: whmcs

I'm using WHMCS 1.5.10. And now I want to add the resellerclub API. But When I clicked "Domain Registrar" on admin page, it opens on a different page. But I'm seeing a corrupted page. Because, when I looking "admin/configregistrars.php" page's source code, the `<head>` section does not appear. Consequently, it does not work on the page buttons.

Example image on my admin/configregistrars.php:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I can't fix this problem because on configregistrars.php's code is encrypted with ioncube. Why do I have this problem? And how can I fix it? I can't click "deactivate" and "configure" buttons because they don't work.

I fixed this problem. I had a memory limit problem. If you have any problems with WHMCS, you can tick Setup-General Settings-Other page's bottom sections.